# tcp message end best practices

Tags: tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

whats the best practice to end a tcp message? I now have my own custom string of characters, but I am paranoid that in a case of blind luck, its possible to transmit something on the wire that can contain your end message chracater(s)/string .

SMTP servers take the enter key, but won't that freak out if a peace of text has "enters" in it and is transmitted on the wire?

I would like to get some ideas on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a custom string as the end indicator, you must ensure that this end indicator won't appear in the message body, using some string escape techniques.

For example, if you are using "\r\n" as the end indicator, you must turn the "\r\n" in the message body to another form.

Comment: ok, after some contemplation.... what if I substitute my end of message delimter somewhere that tis found inside the string, but then my substitution might also be matched somewhere in the string? So when catching it all on the other side... I might mess it up by replacing two occurences of my substitution, where there is essentially only one?

Comment: I know its a long shot... but I am battlign to understand what the "right" way is here... it cant possible be the correct solution to just hope your determined end of message delimeter, or escape substitute, is unique enough?

Comment: This might be useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667803/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-arbitrary-delimiter-escape-character-processing

Answer (score 2):

Can better use the length of message and pass it the beginning?

For example of text protocol seee [here](https://github.com/DeNADev/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL/blob/master/docs-en/protocol.en.txt). Your problem solve it part

```
An encoded string is a string with the following encoding rules.
- Characters in the range [0x10 - 0xff] are encoded as itselves.
- A character in the range [0x00 - 0x0f] is prefixed by 0x01 and
  shifted by 0x40. For example, 0x03 is encoded as 0x01 0x43.
```